# Angular 5.2 app: how to force (check) jQuery to be loaded before Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-cli

I'm working on an app generated using JHipster 4.14.1, which uses Angular 5.2.0.
In this project, I also need to use Bootstrap 4.0.0 and jQuery 3.3.1.
Since Bootstrap depends on jQuery, I must configure the app in such a way that jQuery is loaded before Bootstrap, otherwise it will not work. Here are two related questions:

- [Bootstrap toggle-button not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756307/bootstrap-4-toggle-button-not-working?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
- [Bootstrap before jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681019/should-bootstrap-js-run-after-jquery-js-or-before)

So, my question is: where can I specify the order in which the scripts have to be loaded in an Angular 5.2 app?

Comment: Just add the scripts in correct order in your .angular-cli.json file

Comment: also, you probably should not be using jQuery in an Angular app. See either ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap for a way to use Bootstrap 4 without jQuery

Comment: You don't need Jquery for bootstrap, you simply need the css for all of bootstraps js features, I would take a look at ng-bootstrap.